# How to modify screen dpi in Linux Mint Cinammon?

Tags: linux-mint, dpi, cinnamon

Does anybody knows how to change that? I have a 1920*1080 monitor and everything looks so small for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just bump up the font sizes and/or the icon sizes. The fonts should be under System Settings/Cinnamon Settings. However, if you want full [Hi-DPI support for Cinnnamon](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2014/03/hi-dpi-support-for-cinnamon/), you can test this software which will be included in the next version of Mint.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Hi-DPI setting only allows the options "auto", "manual" (same as auto), and "double". The last option sets the scaling to 200% I assume. That's too much for my Full HD 13 inch display. It does not allow for more granular increments like 125% or 150% like Windows 10 Red 1 and Ubuntu 16.04 does. I'm using Linux Mint 18 alongside of these. For now, Windows 10 has the best appearance on this display, and Ubuntu 16.04 looks almost just as good. Mint is lacking in these terms.

Answer (score -2):

Ty Linux Mint KDE 18.x (plasma) which allows scaling to decimals like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 etc

Comment: Can you provide more information